# Android Slide Menu can not replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to create my  slide menu.wrote code witch can  show /hide slide menu, but now I want replace fragments in listview click listener. When I click listview I can not replace fragments.

This is a my Xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu
        android:id="@+id/slideMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menubutton" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMenu"
            android:background="#ff0000" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is a part my MainActivity.java code:

```
@Override
public void onSlideMenuItemClick(int itemId) {

    navigateTo(itemId);


}


private void navigateTo(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                        StradaBooking.newInstance(),
                        StradaBooking.TAG).commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, StradaContact.newInstance(),
                        StradaContact.TAG).commit();
        break;

    case 2:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, StradaBooking.newInstance(),
                        StradaBooking.TAG).commit();
        break;

    case 3:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, StradaContact.newInstance(),
                        StradaContact.TAG).commit();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error? Try checking if position is correct. Add `Log.d("test","position: " + position);` and check if correct number appears in Logcat.

Comment: I think you are getting the id of the view in `onSlideMenuItemClick` where as you are checking for positions in the switch case. Print the position in log, what does it say?